# How to append values to python list instead of replacing the values with latest value

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Hi the following is my python/django code:

```
values = Record.objects.filter(record_id__in=[1,2,3], is_main_record=True)
if values .filter(status='open'):
   all_item = ['sasi', 'kuttu','vava']
   for item in items:
        values1 = values.filter(set=mask, status='open')
        print values1
```

The above code will give me objects in each item. Now I want to create a dictionary so that I can create a data structure as below:

```
jobs = [
        {'item': 'A', 'device': 'deviceA', 'log': 'logA'},
        {'item': 'A', 'device': 'device1', 'log': 'ptrf1'},
        {'item': 'B', 'device': 'deviceb', 'log': 'ptrfb'},
        {'item': 'C', 'device': 'devicec', 'log': 'ptrfc'},
    ]
```

For that I have added like:

```
 jobs = []
 values = Record.objects.filter(record_id__in=[1,2,3], is_main_record=True)
    if values .filter(status='open'):
       all_item = ['sasi', 'kuttu','vava']
       for mask in all_item:
            values1 = values.filter(set=mask, status='open')
            for x in values1:
                data = {'item' : x.item, 'device':x.device, 'log':x.log}
                jobs.append(data)
            print jobs
```

But jobs always giving me the latest item, instead of the data structure i mentioned above (List of Each items). How can I resolve this and achieve the data structure I mentioned? Sorry new to Python and coding. Please forgive if i asked any stupid question. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You can get rid of all the loops - by just using `.values()` look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jobs = []
values = Record.objects.filter(record_id__in=[1,2,3], is_main_record=True, status='open', set__in=['sasi', 'kuttu','vava'])
if values.exists():
   all_item = ['sasi', 'kuttu','vava']
   for mask in all_item:
       for x in values:
           data = {'item' : x.item, 'device': x.device, 'log': x.log}
           jobs.append(data)

print jobs # <--- print here, then you see the whole list
```

your code is fine, you were just printing inside a loop step which gives you just the momentum value and not the whole list

I have updated the queries, which makes less db queries.

Comment: @BLACKPANTHER please see my updated answer with only one `.filter()`, i would do this way

Comment: Great!! Thanks doniyor!